# ORA-00907 error - incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Attempting to create a very simple table in oracle (apex), but keep getting this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

I have copied and pasted previous answers to this problem which ran OK but when attempting to personalise the error returns.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my syntax?

```
create table location(
    Premises_Ref varchar2(20) primary key,
    Street_Name varchar2(20),  
    Geo_coord int(4), 
    Distance_from_HQ number(10), 
    Daily_Units number(4), 
    Collection_Period varchar2(20)
);
```

Comment: Does the error message give a line number?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `int(4)`.  Use `number(4)` instead.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfa5e) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the precision specifier from the `int` data type:

```
create table location(
    Premises_Ref varchar2(20) primary key,
    Street_Name varchar2(20),  
    Geo_coord int, 
    Distance_from_HQ number(10), 
    Daily_Units number(4), 
    Collection_Period varchar2(20)
);
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bcce